# Search using only part of the string

Tags: mysql, sql

Under a column named "name" I have a row which holds the value "Joe".

What can I use so when I search "Joe Bloggs" it will return the row that only holds "Joe"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  INSTR(:value, name) > 0
```

Where `:value` should be the parameter you will bind to that SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `LIKE`:

```
select *
from t
where $value like concat('%', name, '%');
```

If you want the name "Joe" only at the beginning:

```
select *
from t
where $value like concat(name, '%');
```